# Display dropdown on table data cell in html using angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I am trying to populate rows in my html table based on my angularjs response. My aim is to make one of my table data cell in a drop down format.

**Requirements**:

- The drop down will have three values (A, B and C).
- The initial value should be the value obtained in my
  angularjs response.
- The other values of the dropdown should be the remaining values that is not obtained in the response.

**In detail**:

I have this table row:

```
<tbody>
   <tr valign="middle" st-select-row="row" st-select-mode="multiple" ng-repeat="row in display_republish_records" id="{{row.botMainId}}">
      <td><select class="custom-select" style="margin-left:0px" ng-model="botId" ng-options="choice.name for choice in botIds"></select></td>
      <td ng-bind="row.botSet"></td>
      <td ng-bind="row.botNumber"></td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

And, I have the response data in this format:

```
0: {botMainId: "A", botSet: "HK64604", botNumber: "786443174705883702", $$hashKey: "object:27"}
1: {botMainId: "A", botSet: "HK65825", botNumber: "595143174706013402", $$hashKey: "object:28"}
2: {botMainId: "A", botSet: "HK67383", botNumber: "281943174706142702", $$hashKey: "object:29"}
3: {botMainId: "B", botSet: "HK72557", botNumber: "922443174706654102", $$hashKey: "object:30"}
4: {botMainId: "B", botSet: "HK73332", botNumber: "724243174706716502", $$hashKey: "object:31"}
5: {botMainId: "A", botSet: "HK74025", botNumber: "379943174706764502", $$hashKey: "object:32"}
6: {botMainId: "A", botSet: "HK74694", botNumber: "825843174706807002", $$hashKey: "object:33"}
7: {botMainId: "C", botSet: "HK74819", botNumber: "563543174706827202", $$hashKey: "object:34"}
8: {botMainId: "C", botSet: "HK75964", botNumber: "423643174706902802", $$hashKey: "object:35"}
9: {botMainId: "B", botSet: "HK76384", botNumber: "678043174706923902", $$hashKey: "object:36"}
```

From this data, the dropdown on the first row, second row and third dow should hold the inital value as A and then B, C as the other dropdown values.

The fourth and fifth row should hold B as the initial value and C and A as the other dropdown values and so on.

Now, my js of what I've tried so far:

```
$http({
                                    'url' : '/myURL',
                                    'method' : 'POST',
                                    'headers' : {
                                        'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
                                    }
                                }).then(function(response) {
                                    console.log(response.data);
                                    var arrayLength = response.data.length;
                                    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
                                       /* console.log(response.data[i].botMainId);*/
                                        var botRuleCode1 = null;
                                        var botRuleCode2 = null;
                                        var botRuleCode3 = null;
                                        if (response.data[i].botMainId == 'A'){
                                            botRuleCode1 = 'A';
                                            botRuleCode2 = 'B';
                                            botRuleCode3 = 'C';
                                        } else if (response.data[i].botMainId == 'B'){
                                            botRuleCode1 = 'B';
                                            botRuleCode2 = 'A';
                                            botRuleCode3 = 'C';
                                        } else {
                                            botRuleCode1 = 'C';
                                            botRuleCode2 = 'B';
                                            botRuleCode3 = 'A';
                                        }
                                        $scope.botIds = [ {
                                            id : botRuleCode1,
                                            name : botRuleCode1
                                        }, {
                                            id : botRuleCode2,
                                            name : botRuleCode2
                                        }, {
                                            id : botRuleCode3,
                                            name : botRuleCode3
                                        }];

                                        $scope.botId = $scope.botIds[0];
                                    }
                                    $scope.botData = response.data;

                                    $window.scrollTo(0, 0);

                                })
```

This script will take the last value of the `for` is set for all the dropdowns, making a common dropdown value for all the rows.

Can someone help on how could I change this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are using the same [ngModel](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) `botId` for each row in your [repeater](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).

It would be better to have a different object to store the selection value per each item, so you can fill it right after your data is returned from the API call. Something like this illustrates the described approach:

```js
angular.module("myApp", [])
    .constant('POSSIBLE_OPTIONS', ['A', 'B', 'C'])
    .controller("MyController", ['POSSIBLE_OPTIONS', function (POSSIBLE_OPTIONS) {
        var ctrl = this;

        ctrl.display_republish_records = [
            {botMainId: "A", botSet: "HK64604", botNumber: "786443174705883702"},
            {botMainId: "A", botSet: "HK65825", botNumber: "595143174706013402"},
            {botMainId: "A", botSet: "HK67383", botNumber: "281943174706142702"},
            {botMainId: "B", botSet: "HK72557", botNumber: "922443174706654102"},
            {botMainId: "B", botSet: "HK73332", botNumber: "724243174706716502"},
            {botMainId: "A", botSet: "HK74025", botNumber: "379943174706764502"},
            {botMainId: "A", botSet: "HK74694", botNumber: "825843174706807002"},
            {botMainId: "C", botSet: "HK74819", botNumber: "563543174706827202"},
            {botMainId: "C", botSet: "HK75964", botNumber: "423643174706902802"},
            {botMainId: "B", botSet: "HK76384", botNumber: "678043174706923902"}
        ];

        ctrl.posibbleOptions = getUniqueValuesV2(ctrl.display_republish_records, 'botMainId')
            .map(optionsMapper);

        ctrl.posibbleOptionsFromConstant = POSSIBLE_OPTIONS
            .map(optionsMapper);

        ctrl.selectionModel = {};

        angular.forEach(ctrl.display_republish_records, function (bot) {
            ctrl.selectionModel[bot.botNumber] = ctrl.posibbleOptions.filter(function (opt) {
                return opt.id === bot.botMainId;
            })[0];
        });

        function optionsMapper(id) {
            return {
                id: id,
                name: id
            }
        }


        function getUniqueValues(array, prop) {
            return [...new Set(array.map(item => item[prop]))];
        }
        
        function getUniqueValuesV2(array, prop) {
          return array.map(function(item) {
                      return item[prop];
                    }).filter(function(item, i, ar){ 
                      return ar.indexOf(item) === i;  
                    });
        }

    }]);
```

```css
pre {
    max-width: 100%;
    word-break: break-word;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController as $ctrl">
    <hr/>

    <table>

        <tr valign="middle" st-select-row="row" st-select-mode="multiple"
            ng-repeat="row in $ctrl.display_republish_records track by row.botNumber"
            ng-attr-id="{{::row.botMainId}}-{{::row.botNumber}}">
            <td>
                <select class="custom-select" style="margin-left:0px" ng-model="$ctrl.selectionModel[row.botNumber]"
                        ng-options="choice.name for choice in $ctrl.posibbleOptions track by choice.id">
                    <option value="" hidden readonly="" ng-hide="true"></option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td ng-bind="row.botSet"></td>
            <td ng-bind="row.botNumber"></td>
        </tr>

    </table>


    <hr/>

    <h3>Debug info:</h3>

    <code>
        <pre>{{$ctrl.posibbleOptionsFromConstant}}</pre>
    </code>
    <hr/>

    <code>
        <pre>{{$ctrl.posibbleOptions}}</pre>
    </code>
    <hr/>

    <code>
        <pre>{{$ctrl.selectionModel}}</pre>
    </code>

</div>
```

Comment: You deserve this bounty man !! But just a small clarification. What if my list contains only A and B as the botMainIds. This dropdown will not be populating the option C right? How to bring in that? I suppose you missed that.

Comment: Even though A and B are the only elements in the list, even C should be in the dropdown !

Comment: @Mike hey, hope this helped you! I think to get all the possible values - the best way of doing this - is to make an API call that would query db for all the possible options (probably filtered by some other business logic before going to the client). A bit easier way - is to have it as a `constant` (see how `ctrl.posibbleOptionsFromConstant` is populated) in you angularjs module. I avoided your `if/else` method of populating the option list just for the simplicity of the example.

Comment: Great man ! That was what I did. You got it :) Thanks for your help much !!

Comment: Stanislav.. The `getUniqueValues` function. Can I achieve this without the scope operator?

Comment: @Mikedo you mean something like `getUniqueValuesV2`? See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I have an example create for this case but i hope it helps.

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module('MyApp', [])
        app.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $window) {
            $scope.Customers = [
                { Name: "John Hammond", Country: "United States" },
                { Name: "Mudassar Khan", Country: "India" },
                { Name: "Suzanne Mathews", Country: "France" },
                { Name: "Robert Schidner", Country: "Russia" }
               ];
            $scope.GetDetails = function () {
                var details = '';
                $('[id*=tblCustomers] tr:not(:has(th))').each(function (index, item) {
                    var name = $scope.Customers[index].Name;
                    var country = $scope.Customers[index].Country;
                    var selected = $(item).find('[id*=ddlYesNo] option:selected').val()
                    details += "Name: " + name + "\nCountry: " + country + "\nAction: " + selected + "\n\n";
                });
                $window.alert(details);
            };
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">
        <table id="tblCustomers" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    Country
                </th>
                <th>
                    Action
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tbody ng-repeat="m in Customers">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        {{m.Name}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{m.Country}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select id="ddlYesNo">
                            <option value="">Select</option>
                            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                            <option value="No">No</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <br />
        <input type="button" value="Get Details" ng-click="GetDetails()" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Xenis for your answer. However, the condition should be for the select dropdown. The requirement is, whenever the div is loaded, the default value of the dropdown should be based on the response obtained.

Comment: Consider the dropdown is assigned to the Country option.
Assume this data: John from USA, Mudassar from India, Suzanne from USA again and Robert from Russia, the Country dropdown should have USA as default for John and Suzanne. (The other values should be India and Russia)
And for Robert, the default value should be Russia. The other values should be USA and India. Hope I am clear

Comment: Yeah i understand what you mean. i will have a try to create a better Ex.

Answer (score 0):

1. This is JS for showing listing with drop down in it

   ```
   incidentDataList = [{IncidentId:1,Name:'Test',Description:'Test',AssignedUser: 'demo', IncidentStatus: 'Open'},{IncidentId:1,Name:'Test',Description:'Test',AssignedUser: 'demo', IncidentStatus: 'Resolved'}];
   $scope.updateStatus = function (incidentData,index) {
    const headers = {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true'
    };
    $scope.showerror = false;
    $scope.alert.error = "";
    $scope.showsuccess = false;
    $scope.alert.success = "";
    incidentData.IncidentStatus = $scope.incidentDataList[index].IncidentStatus;
    $http.put('/updateIncident', JSON.stringify(incidentData),{ 'headers': headers }).then(function (response) {
        if (response.data)
        {    $scope.showsuccess = true;
             $scope.alert.success = "Status " + incidentData.IncidentStatus +" updated successfully ";
             $scope.incidentData = {};
        }
    }, function (response) {
        if (response.data)
        {    
            $scope.showerror = true;
            $scope.alert.error = "Error while updating " + $scope.incidentData.Name;
        }
    });
   ```

   }
2. This is you HTML code, write this select code inside list

   ```
   <select ng-change="updateStatus(data,$index)" ng-model="incidentDataList[$index].IncidentStatus" class="form-control" ng-options="x for x in IncidentStatusList" aria-describedby="IncidentStatus" placeholder="Incident Status">
   ```

Select Incident Status